# How scanf works if I add a new line '\n' at the end

Tags: c, newline, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int a,b,c;

    scanf("%d%d%d\n",&a,&b,&c);
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

Look I am taking 3 inputs and printing 3 outputs... But as I added a new line at the end of the scanf function I have to give 4 inputs to get 3 outputs(I get the first 3 I give as input)... How scanf works here? 
And in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(){ 

    double n[2][5]; int i,j; 

    for (i=0;i<=1;i++){ 

        for(j=0;j<=4;j++){ 

            scanf("%lf\n",&n[i][j]); 
            printf("Class=%d Roll=%d Marks=%lf\n",i+6,j+1,n[i][j]); 

        } 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Look I have to give 11 inputs to get the 10 outputs... And each time I give a input I get the previous input as an output... How scanf is working here?

Comment: If you want to print 3 output, you need to give 4 input, what is the forth input? Say the first 3 are a,b and c.

Comment: just any kind of arbitrary input... in this case any integer... But the program only prints the first 3 inputs...

Comment: `"%d%d%d\n"` --> `"%d%d%d"` , `"%lf\n"` --> `"%lf"`

Comment: Avoid using `scanf()`.  Consider `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` and/or `strto*()`.  If you must use `scanf()`, check its return value.

Answer (score 2):

A white character in scanf format matches a sequence of white characters in the input until a non-white character.

Newline is a white character and this explains the behavior of your program. Meaning that if your scanf format terminates by a newline, it does not finish until it sees an additional non-blank character after the last parsed input.

Comment: Hmm... This explains the first program... But look at the second one... If what you said is true then shouldn't I have to give 20 inputs? 
Maybe it happens cause each time it starts the loop it scans the previous given number as an input... Hmm,that explains things... 
Thank you... :)

Comment: In each loop it scans one number and all spaces until the next number (but this another number is not read). So, you have to insert 10 numbers and some other character (which may be another number) to scan 10 numbers.

Comment: Yes while running the loop for the first time it takes 2 inputs but reads only the first one... 
When the loop is run for the second time it takes another input but reads the 2nd input...
And after running the loop for 10 times it doesn't need to read the 11th input...

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is only used to input values, now what you need is the your output to be on a new line, basically you want a newline to be printed on your screen, so you must use the `\n` in the `printf` as you want a new line to be printed.As for why it is asking for four inputs , Im not sure, the syntax says that you must  you use `%` and a letter according to the type of data to be accepted, Ill read more on this and Get back.
Thank You.