# how scanf handles standard input vs pipelined input

Tags: c++, input, printf, output, scanf

In the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int N;
char x[110];
int main() {
    scanf("%d\n", &N);
    while (N--) {
        scanf("0.%[0-9]...\n", x);
        printf("the digits are 0.%s\n", x);
    }
}
```

when I enter the input through file using command

> ./a.out < "INPUTFILE"

It works as expected but when I enter the input through std input it delay the `printf` function.

Why is that?

Input

> 3
>   0.1227...
>   0.517611738...
>   0.7341231223444344389923899277...

Output through file

> the digits are 0.1227
>   the digits are 0.517611738
>   the digits are 0.7341231223444344389923899277

output through standard input

> the digits are 0.1227
>   the digits are 0.517611738

The code is from a book, *commpetitive programing 3 ch1_02_scanf.cpp*.

Comment: See "How scanf works if I add a new line '\n' at the end": 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033265/how-scanf-works-if-i-add-a-new-line-n-at-the-end for the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there's an extra `\n` in your `scanf` format string, it will read and discard *ALL* whitespaces (spaces, newlines and tabs, if present). There needs to be an indication of the end of a whitespace sequence, so you should either hit Ctrl-D for EOF, or enter another non-WS character that lets `scanf` stop.

As *Sid S* suggests, you cam alternatively change your format string like this:

```
scanf(" 0.%[0-9]...", x);
```

The program works because when you redirect its stdin to a file, `scanf` will know if it reaches EOF and terminates the last input. You need to manually give an EOF when you type from console. That's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Change the second scanf() line to

```
scanf(" 0.%[0-9]...", x);
```